# Github pages not working properly in respnonsive view

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, responsive, responsive-images

[In browser responsive view it seems fine. All things working properly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QfGU3.png)

[But when I view it on my android phone. It doesn't align properly. I tested it on many devices. All results are the same.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YQd8q.jpg)
What is the problem? Can anyone help? This is very weird

Answer (score 1):

You can try to add this to your style sheet:

```css
body{
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}
```